# Symfony Form Validation: UniqueEntity - multiple fields - including one nullable field

Tags: php, symfony, validation

**Situation:** I have an form based on an entity. This entity has two properties *country* and *staticRank* and the tuple of both these both properties should be unique... **BUT:** the *staticRank* could isn't required and due to that, it can be null. I tried solving that problem using the *UniqueEntity* annotation:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"country", "staticRank"})
```

This isn't working like expected, because if the *staticRank* is *null* it should be a valid combination according to my definition. However, there are several tuples given with the same *country* and *null* (for the *staticRank*), so the constraint notes a violation.

**Actual Question:** Is there a way to archieve this behaviour without inheriting the "UniqueEntityValidator"?

EDIT: As far as I've experienced, the *ignoreNull*-property of the constraint would just allow both values to be null (or if the constraint is only set to a single field)

Comment: Are country and staticRank entities in a manytoMany relationship or just fields of an entity ?

Comment: @Mawcel country is a ManyToOne, staticRank is just a field (both used in the same entity)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810738/unique-values-for-two-columns-in-doctrine

Comment: @Mawcel thanks, that would work on the ORM side and already had that in my code, but I was searching for something that I could use to validate the form on submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved that problem by passing a service into my Type (inherited from "AbstractType") and adding a constraint option:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setRequired('myService');
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        // ...
        'constraints' => [
            new Callback([
                'callback' => [$this, 'checkCountryRankUniqueness']
            ])
        ]
    ]);
}
```

In that constraint method, I checked whether the *staticRank* is null. If it isn't null, it will iterate over all objects and check whether the combination is unique.